# Using lattitude and longitude of the current location and destination location , how can we get the direction in iphone

Tags: iphone, google-maps, direction

I am working in 1 iphone app where we need to show the direction from 1 place to other place 
That is from current location in which direction (N or E or W or S or NE or NW or SE or SW ) the destination is .
I know how to get the directions from 1 place to another place but I am searching for showing the direction . 
Is my problem clear ? If any one know how to do it , Pleae help me 
Thanks every one!

Comment: @Joe Blow - not drawing  Arrow the output should like Diatance : 1km northwest , I found distance searching for direction

Comment: yes I want the answer like N or E or W or S or NE or NW or SE or SW

Answer (score 3):

Do you know the coordinates of the two locations?

Look at [CLLocationCoordinate2D](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010238):

> **latitude**
>   The latitude in degrees. Positive values indicate latitudes north of the equator. Negative values indicate latitudes south of the equator.
>
> **longitude**
>   The longitude in degrees. Measurements are relative to the zero meridian, with positive values extending east of the meridian and negative values extending west of the meridian.

Latitude is therefore quite simple, if the destination's latitude is less than the current location's latitude then it lies to the north, if it is greater than the current location's latitude then it lies to the south.

`latitudinal_distance = destination.latitude - origin.latitude`

Longitude is slightly more complex as you should consider that a destination three quarters of the way around the Earth to the east is probably better expressed as being to the west. Again compare the longitude values, consider the distance both east and west, handle crossing the meridian, and choose the shorter distance.

`distance_east = (origin.longitude > 0 && destination.longitude < 0) ? 180 - origin.longitude + destination.longitude - -180 : destination.longitude - origin.longitude; if (distance_east < 0) distance_east += 360`

`distance_west = (origin.longitude < 0 && destination.longitude > 0) ? -180 - origin.longitude - 180 - destination.longitude : origin.longitude - destination.longitude; if (distance_west < 0) distance_west += 360`

`longitudinal_distance = min(distance_east, distance_west)`

Once you know how many degrees of latitude and longitude separate your two points you can calculate a heading to your destination and decide which heading should be show as which compass points. On a compass with only four points (N, E, S, W) each point would cover 90 degrees. On a compass with 8 points each point would cover 45 degrees. Hopefully you get the idea.

`heading = arctan(longitudinal_distance / latitudinal_distance)`
`if (heading >= -45 || heading < 45) return 'N'; else if (heading >= 45 && heading < 135) return 'E'; else if ...`

It's late here and I'm not testing those expressions so if they seem useful please make sure you understand and test them instead of trying to apply them blindly. The odds that I transposed a sign or coordinate pair are unfortunately high.

Comment: Hi Jonah , Thanks for Your response and answer , I have tried the code and using heading value I wrote like below : if (heading >= -45 || heading < 0)  return @"North"; else if (heading >= 0 && heading < 45)  return @"East"; else if(heading>=45 && heading < 90) return @"South"; else if(heading>=90 && heading<135) return @"West";else if(heading>=135 && heading < 180) return @"North East"; else if (heading >= 180 || heading < 225) return @"North West"; else if (heading >= 225 && heading < 270) return @"South East"; else if(heading>=270 && heading < 315) return @"South West"; is this correct

Comment: Did you try it? You seem to be assuming that heading will range from 0 to 360 which does not match with the assumptions I made in my example. Take a look at how those values are calculated and consider what the possible outputs are.

Comment: Yes I assumed like u said . is  that wrong ? can u tell me how I need to do?

Comment: I will try to help if you still have specific questions but I think I have given you everything you need to solve this problem.

Comment: Yes but I guess my code is wrong .. I understand your answer as we should take 0 to 360 to check the direction. can u help me by seeing my code above Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the magnetometer / core location sample by Apple: [Teslameter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Teslameter/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: The OP wants to know the direction between two points on a map and you're suggesting to read the compass. Those are two totally different things.

Comment: Thanks BojanG , is it not possible with Google maps api ?