# Showing an arrow that is heading a specific location

Tags: iphone, ios4, compass-geolocation, cllocationmanager, cllocation

Does anyone know how to place out an arrow that points to a specific annotation depending on my current heading. For example; I want the arrow to be vertical when the current heading is the same as the annotation's coordinates. 
I am offering 50$ to the one doing this thing for me via paypal
Have a look at the picture below;

[image]

.

Comment: I know exactly how to use the trigonometry involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to do the same thing as [Using lattitude and longitude of the current location and destination location , how can we get the direction in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632966/using-lattitude-and-longitude-of-the-current-location-and-destination-location/4633171#4633171) get the heading between your current position and some destination, then compare that heading with your current heading to determine which direction that arrow should face.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you set the arrows rotation using on screen coordinates and then rotate the view containing the map and the arrow, so that north is always up?

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like:

```
- (void) updateHeading
{
    [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];     
    locationManager.headingFilter = kCLHeadingFilterNone;
}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager  didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading*)newHeading
{
    heading = newHeading.trueHeading;
    heading += -90.0 * roll;
    NSLog(@"Your Heading: %@", heading);

    NSLog(@"magneticHeading: %f", newHeading.magneticHeading);
    NSLog(@"trueHeading: %f", newHeading.trueHeading);
}
```

Also, see [`magneticHeading`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLHeading_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLHeading/magneticHeading) and [`truHeading`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLHeading_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLHeading/trueHeading) in the [CLHeading Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLHeading_Class/Reference/Reference.html)